# Per Pixel collision when animate sprites

Tags: xna, jquery-animate, pixel

This is what I have for detecting collision.

```
 public static bool IntersectPixels(Rectangle rectangleA, Color[] dataA, Rectangle rectangleB, Color[] dataB)
    {
        int top = Math.Max(rectangleA.Top, rectangleB.Top);
        int bottom = Math.Min(rectangleA.Bottom, rectangleB.Bottom);
        int left = Math.Max(rectangleA.Left, rectangleB.Left);
        int right = Math.Min(rectangleA.Right, rectangleB.Right);
        for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
        {
            for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
            {
                Color colorA = dataA[(x - rectangleA.Left) + (y - rectangleA.Top) * rectangleA.Width];
                Color colorB = dataB[(x - rectangleB.Left) + (y - rectangleB.Top) * rectangleB.Width];
                if (colorA.A != 0 && colorB.A != 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }:
```

It work fine until I want to animate stuff. So I have a texture sprite that have about 12 frame. what I need to do is get the color data array of each frame. This is how I get the color data array:

```
 Color[] playerColorArray = new Color[playerColorArray.X * playerColorArray.Y];
 PlayerTexture.GetData(playerColorArray);
 CData = playerColorArray;
```

Now my guess is that i have to update the textureData everytime the frame changes
Is there a way to get the the color data from each frame only?

Comment: the trick is in getting the right color[] data, please show us these methods and how you animate your sprites

Answer (score 1):

You can get an array of the complete sprite sheet texture and only use the current frame.

Let's say you have a sprite sheet and `stride` is the offset of a pixel to the pixel below it. This can be the sprite sheet's width. Furthermore, you have the position `x0`, `y0` of the first pixel of the current frame. Then you just have to modify the index calculation:

```
int posXInFrame = (x - rectangleA.Left);
int posYInFrame = (y - rectangleA.Top);
Color colorA = dataA[(posXInFrame + x0) + (posYInFrame + y0) * stride];
```

Probably, you have calculated `x0` and `y0` somewhere else and can pass those values to the function.